# How do I add a default date value to a mongoose schema on typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema on typescript:

```js
@Schema({collection: 'collection.name'})
export class myCollection extends Document {
    @Prop()
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
    @Prop()
    name: string;
    @Prop()
    _created: Date
}

export const myCollectionSchema = SchemaFactory.createForclass(myCollection)
```

However, I would like to set the default value of _created to the current time. I've tried using the following methods with no success:

```js
_created : {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
}
//I get "'(' expected" ?
```

```js
_created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
//I get: 'Public property '_created' of exported class has or is using private name 'Date''
```

```js
//before Schema declaration
let getTime = function() {
    return new Date();
}

_created: {
    type: Date,
    default: getTime
}
//'getTime' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof getTime'?
//Public property '_created' of exported class has or is using private name 'getTime'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing the following for whenever I wanted to insert a new document with those default values (in my case, using findoneandupdate):

```js
//file.ts
let newDocument = {
    _created = new Date()
}
this.myCollectionModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: someid}, $seOnInsert: newDocument}, {upsert: true})
```

note that using await before the query would result in duplicate values